# Send a PostGIS object through RestFul service (JSON)

Tags: java, json, rest, postgis

all.

This is my first question, so forgive if I do anything wrong. Here we go.

I have a problem while trying to send a PostGIS Object (actually a PGgeometry) through a RestFul service.

The class I'm trying to send is GPSMessageFormat:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="position")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType( propOrder = {
    "latitude",
    "longitude",
    "position",
    } )
public class GPSMessageFormat implements Serializable{

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 4178516023632486216L;

  public Double latitude;

  public Double longitude;

  public PointJaxRS position;
}
```

I have created my own class that implements PGgeometry in order to add the needed tags:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class PointJaxRS extends PGgeometry {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 4624155439994995423L;

  public PointJaxRS(){
    super();
  };
}
```

This is the exception that reached:

```
org.postgis.Geometry does not have a no-arg default constructor.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at org.postgis.Geometry
        at org.postgis.Point
        at es.datatype.PointJaxRS
        at public es.datatype.PointJaxRS es.datatype.GPSMessageFormat.position
        at es.datatype.GPSMessageFormat
Class has two properties of the same name "m"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public double org.postgis.Point.getM()
        at org.postgis.Point
        at es.datatype.PointJaxRS
        at public es.datatype.PointJaxRS es.datatype.GPSMessageFormat.position
        at es.datatype.GPSMessageFormat
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public double org.postgis.Point.m
        at org.postgis.Point
        at es.datatype.PointJaxRS
        at public es.datatype.PointJaxRS es.datatype.GPSMessageFormat.position
        at es.datatype.GPSMessageFormat

[...] **Other similar errors with all the other fields from PGgeometry**
```

I thought that adding the ***@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)*** tag was enough to recognize only the attributes from the class as fields in the json file, but it seems that this does not work for inherited attributes. In addition, I would need Geometry to have a no-arg default constructor...

I can't send them as String because they are going to be received by Openlayers, so it needs to be able to read the PGgeometry in order to draw the points in a map.

So the question is: what can I do to send PostGIS objets in JSON format through rest services?